# Having issue creating a datatable after passing an argument

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I am taking a reference from this [site](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2015/08/jquery-datatables-get-data-from.html). But I have made a slight change in it which is, I am passing an argument which gets branchId. I only wanted to show which are in particlular branch but I am having a issue about how can I return with data as I am having an error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'branchId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void
>   GetEmployeeLists(Int32)' in 'xxx (filelocation)'. To make a parameter
>   optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable
>   type. Parameter name: parameters

MyController

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetEmployeeLists(int branchId)
{
    var id = this._branches.GetById(branchId);
    string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appDB"];
    List<EmployeeList> lstDatas = new List<EmployeeList>();
    string query = "SELECT " +
                @"el.id, " +
                @"el.name, " +
                @"el.role " +
                @"FROM employee_list el;"

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 3000;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EmployeeList lstData = new EmployeeList();
                    lstData.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                    lstData.Name = reader["name"].ToString();
                    lstData.Role = reader["role"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        HttpContext.Response.Write(js.Serialize(lstDatas));
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

MyView which contains script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '<%=this.Url.Action("GetEmployeeLists", "Admin") %>',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    paging: true,
                    sort: true,
                    searching: true,
                    scrollY: 200,
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                            { 'data': 'Id' },
                            { 'data': 'Name' },
                            { 'data': 'Role' },
                        ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *Read* the error. It complains about the *method's* parameters, not the database. Your Javascript code doesn't pass the required `branchId` parameter

Comment: Yes I know, its not database its the parameter I am passing but how can I solve this issue with parameter is the question here.

Comment: Just pass the parameter in Url.Action. Where is `branchId` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created that this way and I was able solve that issue. However, I have used datatable legacy so you might have to change some of the part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var branchId = '<%=ViewData["branchId"]%>';
        $.ajax({
        url: '.../Admin/GetEmployeeLists', (Needs to change that as per your method location)
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                branchId: branchId
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bSearchable": true,
                    "sScrollY": "200px",
                    "aaData": data,
                    "aoColumns": [
                            { 'data': 'Id' },
                            { 'data': 'Name' },
                            { 'data': 'Role' },
                        ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also you need to add the viewdata into your controller

```
public void GetEmployeeLists(int branchId)
{
...
ViewData["branchId"] = branchId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the database. As the error says:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter **'branchId'** of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method **'Void GetEmployeeLists(Int32)'** in 'xxx (filelocation)

Your method requires a `branchId` parameter but your Javascript code didn't pass one:

```
url: '<%=this.Url.Action("GetEmployeeLists", "Admin") %>'
```

You should pass the `branchId` parameter to the action, eg:

```
url: '<%=this.Url.Action("GetEmployeeLists", "Admin", new { branchId = 123 }) %>'
```